# a tag with "data-method" and "data-confirm" attributes - how does it work?

Tags: html

Are those data attributes part of hmtl5? Are they used by jQuery? I though data- attributes are generic. Why does one bring up a confirmation box and how does the link be converted to POST when data-method is post?

I have searched for these attributes in the web but could not find anything useful. I just saw those attributes are often mentioned with ruby stuff.

Is there any official documentation?

**Update:**

I found out know that they are used in [Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/1d6a340534a79fe2ce79db82abbf653a3c39cd7e/framework/assets/yii.js#L285). However, it seems that other (ruby) frameworks using those attributes in the same way ([example](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery#data-confirm-confirmation-dialogs-for-links-and-forms)). That seems to be the reason why I've got the impression that it is part of jQuery or html5.

Comment: i don't know which part you consider as unuseful. you should have look up this -http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application. It's also commonly used in javascript to target certain elements like so `$('li[data-confirm="popup"]')`

If there is a confirmation box appearing because of an action on this element, it's likely being targeted in the javascript based on the data attribute

Comment: well data attributes themselves have nothing to do with jQuery, their part of the html markup. However, jQuery functions will comonly use this to target their elements

Comment: for instance in bootstrap they have a component for Modals. When your building the html structure any button with the data attribute `data-dismiss="modal"` will close the modal when clicked

Answer (score 15):

> Are those data attributes part of hmtl5?

Data attributes are. Those specific ones are not. The whole point of data attributes is that they are for custom extensions.

> Are they used by jQuery?

Only in the sense that it provides an API to interact with data attributes in general.

> I though data- attributes are generic.

They are.

> Why does one bring up a confirmation box and how does the link be converted to POST when data-method is post?

Because JavaScript code on the page looks for them.

> Is there any official documentation?

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: Thank you for linking to the spec.